# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'pdf'

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm studying the possibility to use the scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.
Starting from the beginning, I'm trying to redo the example of the documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html?highlight=multivariate_normal#scipy.stats.multivariate_normal).
Unfortunately, I'm getting the error message : "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'pdf'".
Am I missing a module or something ?
Thanx in advance.
Nicolas

Comment: Could you provide your code? It looks like you're trying to access `pdf` attribute of `numpy.ndarray` instead of `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal`

Comment: Filip,Thank you for your answer. It's a first order study, I'm only trying to redo exactly the code provided in the documentation : x, y = np.mgrid[-1:1:.01, -1:1:.01]
pos = np.dstack((x, y))
rv = multivariate_normal([0.5, -0.2], [[2.0, 0.3], [0.3, 0.5]])
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
ax2.contourf(x, y, rv.pdf(pos))

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the code you have written, so that it is a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)